# Undefined variable: lang laravel

Tags: variables, laravel

I got a problem the file cannot find the variable 'lang'.

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'loon.language']) }}
   {{Form::select('lang',['nl'=>'nl','po'=>'po'], $lang,['onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
   {{$lang = 'blaat'}}
   {{var_dump($lang)}}
{{ Form::close()}}
```

Controller:

```
public function postChangeLanguage() 
    {
        $rules = [
        'language' => 'in:nl,po' //list of supported languages of your application.
        ];

        $language = Input::get('lang'); //lang is name of form select field.

        $validator = Validator::make(compact($language),$rules);

        // $language = Session::get('language',Config::get('app.locale'));

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            Session::put('language',$language);
            App::setLocale($language);
        }
        else
        { /**/ }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('language', array(
    'uses' =>'LoonController@postChangeLanguage',
    'as' => 'loon.language'
));
```

Filter.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $language = Session::get('language','nl'); //en will be the default language.
    App::setLocale($language);
});
```

Ill even tried to debug it and still this error code!

Undefined variable: lang (View: /Users/nielsvandijk/loon/rekentool/app/views/partials/header.blade.php) (View: /Users/nielsvandijk/loon/rekentool/app/views/partials/header.blade.php)

Can someone help?

Comment: define $lang and pass it to your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you are using $lang it is still empty apparently.. 
A quick fix would be to use an @ sing in front of it (allowing it to be undefined)

```
{{Form::select('lang',['nl'=>'nl','po'=>'po'], @$lang,['onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
```

The purpose of the lang variable is to define the "selected" element in the select field

```
{{Form::select('lang',['nl'=>'nl','po'=>'po'], 'po',['onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
```

This would result in:

```
<select name="lang">
 <option value="nl">nl</option>
 <option value="po" selected="selected">po</option>
</select>
```

In the controller you could set the default language if no language is preselected

```
View::make('view')->with('lang','nl');
```